# Networkx- finding the parallel edges of multiDigraph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a multidigraph like this-

```
Import Networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(1,0)
G.add_edge(1,3)
```

Any networkx way to find edge 0-1 and 1-0 are parallel?

Comment: You can use this - [simple-cycles](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles)

Comment: Isn't it just a cycle? Parallel edges means the edges must have same source and destination nodes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in `networkx` functions for this problem, as I know. But `networkx` stores graph nodes and edges in iterable structures, so you can process them one by one like this:

```
# For every node in graph
for node in G.nodes(): 
    # We look for adjacent nodes
    for adj_node in G[node]: 
        # If adjacent node has an edge to the first node
        # Or our graph have several edges from the first to the adjacent node
        if node in G[adj_node] or len(G[node][adj_node]) > 1: 
            # DO MAGIC!!
            print(node, adj_node)
```

I think it is the most `networkx`-ish code that can solve your problem. Note, that the more sparse graph is, the faster will it work. In the worst case - the complete graph - the complexity is O(n^2). In the best case - very sparse graph -  O(n).